# Django: How to limit results in a modelformset_factory instance

Tags: python, django

I have a model like this:

```
class WordAudio(models.Model):    
    word = models.ForeignKey(Word)
    audio = models.FilePathField(path='media/study_audio/', recursive=True)
    source = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='Unknown')

class Definition(models.Model):
    '''Table for the definitions and examples'''

    ...
    audio = models.ForeignKey(WordAudio, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    image = models.ForeignKey(WordImage, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    ...
```

and I have a modelformset_factory like this:

```
class DefinitionReview(BaseModelFormSet):

    def filter_audio():
        """
        Method to filter out the unwanted audio sections 
        """
        print "call to filter_audio"

DefinitionInfoForm = modelformset_factory(
    Definition, 
    fields=('part_speech', 'definition', 'def_source', 'pronunciation', 'others', 'audio', 'image'), 
    extra=1,
    formset=DefinitionReview
)
```

This method was going to be my attempt at filtering out some `WordAudio` objects. I cannot use the `FilePathField` regex, because that is only limiting the choices when creating the `WordAudio` objects.

The only other way I could think is to call some logic in the template, but I am having trouble getting anything to work in the django shell.

My eventual filter (once I figure out where to begin writing it, will limit the choices for `Definition.image` to only those that correspond to some regex like `word_name[1-9]?.mp3` or something similar.

Where or how can I call such a method in Django?

Comment: Could you explain a little bit more? I have trouble figuring out if this is a purely formset related thing or not. What's your desired behavior in the formset?

Comment: I have an fk to the WordAudio model. The formset displays a choice field with ALL of my WordAudio objects in the template. I want a way to limit which choices get displayed based on a regex or fk (maybe WordAudios fk to Word)

Comment: Hmm, perhaps a dynamic `limit_choices_to` in the child form could do the trick.